# How to fix javascript code to scrollbar works? (background that move when cursor move)

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/rEDIC

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var movementStrength = 25;
var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
$("#top-image").mousemove(function(e){
          var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
          var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
          var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
          var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
          $('#top-image').css("background-position", newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");
});
});
```

here code i use it on body tag

and scrollbar on page visible

but not active iwn if page overflow (so i can see only top of page)
and when i add in css overflow: scroll; to unactive scrollbar adds works scroll
so its 2 scroll bars on right side

so how to fix code so i can scroll page?)